# cordova phonegap page hanging during ajax call

Tags: jquery, iphone, xcode, cordova, xcode4.2

I am using cordova phonegap for a mobile application. Using set time out function i am calling some data through ajax after page load. But while i am using it app are getting hanged for the time interval during the ajax data transfer . After that all are running fine. How to solve it, any idea

```
window.setTimeout(function(){

                                  // $("#home").slideDown(1000);

                                  // $("#home").addClass('curr');

                                  $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: +1, maxDate: "+12M" });
                                  var twitterBox = $("#twitterBox");
                                  $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=santanu1122&callback=?", function(tweetdata) {
                                            twitterBox.append("<p id=\"twitterUser\" class=\"twick\"><a onclick=\"newWin(this.href);return false;\" href=\"http://twitter.com/"+tweetdata.screen_name+"\">@"+tweetdata.screen_name+"</a><br/>Followers: "+tweetdata.followers_count+" Tweets: "+tweetdata.statuses_count+"</p>\n");
                                            getTweets();
                                            });

                                  $.ajax({
                                         type: "POST",
                                         url: "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/fetchnewsfeed.php",
                                         data:"",
                                         success: function(newsfeedbyadmindetails){
                                         $('#newsfeedbyadmin').html(newsfeedbyadmindetails);
                                         $('#example1').fbWall({ id:'santanu.ece',accessToken:'XXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'});
                                         }
                                         }).bind();

                                  }, 5500);
```

Comment: glad to see the rate improved - now, how much data do you change on page normally? if it's too many changes in your document, mobile browsers will choke and only resume when they processed these changes - thus probably hanging your browser only "sometimes", when there is not as much data to change

Comment: ya, data from facebook post, twitter post, as well as data from database in time of app load. If this is not the convenient way then how should i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to scale this all - don't load it all together, load facebook first, then load twitter few seconds afterwartd etc...

Tou can even split results from twitter if they are too many. Then you can update 20 results every few seconds - just make sure the page does not scroll too much outside of the current view, if possible.

Another way would be to use a message - something like "Loading..." while you do updates and hide it afterwards.

It really depends on what user experience you're looking for.